# placing text center to border space above it

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-tables

In below code how to place text center to the border space just above it as illustrated in the screenshot below "Some Text 1" and "Some Text 2" are in the center to the border space above them.

[image]

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.Column {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
}

.Column:nth-child(1) {
  width:20%;
}
.Column:nth-child(2) {
  width:50%;
}
.Column:nth-child(3) {
  width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">C1</div>
  <div class="Column">C2</div>
  <div class="Column">C3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `.Column {text-align: center;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with placing your text elements in the cells, setting them to `position: absolute;` and push them 50% of their own width out of the cell with `transform: translate(50%, 0);`.

Of course you'll need proper vendor prefixes to support older browsers.

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.Column {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.Column:nth-child(1) {
  width:20%;
}
.Column:nth-child(2) {
  width:50%;
}
.Column:nth-child(3) {
  width:30%;
}

.Column > span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 1.5em;
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">C1<span>Some Text 1</span></div>
  <div class="Column">C2<span>Some Text 2</span></div>
  <div class="Column">C3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it does! What browser are you using? Are you the downvoter?

Comment: for me it works as expected. but thanks for the hint, I'll add a `text-align:center` rule to avoid this line breaking issue. But I think this was not the OPs problem

Comment: no but it could be the OP's problem going forward! Might also be an idea to add the vendor prefixes to the answer to help others looking at the answer.

Comment: If that is why you're downvoting me, than please, keep your downvote. Everybody can do the vendor prefixing for their own, as it just blows the code and decreases clarity in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use pseudo-elements to add text and position it with `position:absolute` and `transform: translate()`

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
.Column {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.Column:nth-child(1) {
  width: 20%;
}
.Column:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50%;
}
.Column:nth-child(3) {
  width: 30%;
}
.Column:nth-child(1):after,
.Column:nth-child(2):after {
  content: 'Some text 1';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
}
.Column:nth-child(2):after {
  content: 'Some text 2';
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">C1</div>
  <div class="Column">C2</div>
  <div class="Column">C3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI CSS tranform browser suppoer is IE10+ only: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer using table layout to keep it consistent with what your doing:

```css
    .Row {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-spacing: 10px;
    }

    .Column {
      display: table-cell;
      background-color: red;
    }

    .Column:nth-child(1) {
      width:20%;
    }
    .Column:nth-child(2) {
      width:50%;
    }
    .Column:nth-child(3) {
      width:30%;
    }

    .Row2 {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-spacing: 10px;
      
    }

    .Column2 {
      display: table-cell;
      text-align:center;
      width:40%;
    }

    .Column2:nth-child(2) {
      width:60%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="Row">
      <div class="Column">C1</div>
      <div class="Column">C2</div>
      <div class="Column">C3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row2">
      <div class="Column2">Some Text 1</div>
      <div class="Column2">Some Text 2</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry. I didn't note you answer. THey are really similar. Will delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with new markup with `position: absolute;`

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.Column {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

.Column:nth-child(1) {
  width:20%;
}
.Column:nth-child(2) {
  width:50%;
}
.Column:nth-child(3) {
  width:30%;
}

.Column > span {
  position: absolute;
  right: -45px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">C1<span>Some Text 1</span></div>
  <div class="Column">C2<span>Some Text 2</span></div>
  <div class="Column">C3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't handle variable text lengths... hardcoding the `right` property isn't a good idea...

Comment: I know but for exact markup I provided this solution.